# Declarative models with a dynamic base (SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, declarative

I have a number of models defined in one place that needs to be shared to multiple codebases (that each only need access to a specific subset of the models). Specifically, a unified API needs to query all these models, but a number of data processing projects only needs to query specific models.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Model1(Base):
    ...

class Model2(Base):
    ...

class Model3(Base):
    ...
```

With the above as the basis, is it possible to have a "dynamic" `Base` so that project 1 can have a Base that contains only `Model3`, while project 2 has a Base that contains `Model1` and `Model3`.

A solution would be for each project to declare an "empty" Base, split the entire model up into segments, and for each project then to import each "sub-Base" that they would need, and merge that into their own empty Base. From the documentation of SQLALchemy I cannot tell if this is currently possible.

Ideally, being able to import a specific model and add it to my own Base would be optimal.